# How to get Blu-Ray video from Windows 7 computer upstairs to HDTV downstairs

Tags: networking, media, htpc, hdtv, blu-ray

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 desktop computer upstairs, which has a BD drive, and an HDTV downstairs which has no BD player.  I also have a spare computer (which is currently running Linux, but I could replace with Windows if given a working solution), a Wii (connected to the network), and an Ethernet connection near the TV.  I would like to watch BDs on the HDTV downstairs, without moving either.  The computer does have the hardware and software to play BDs, including HDCP compatible monitors locally (the HDTV is also HDCP compatible) and PowerDVD DX.  However, I do not have a Windows Media Center Extender, a 75' DVI or HDMI cable, or the desire to move the computer downstairs or the TV upstairs.  I would, of course, like to spend as little money as possible.

To summarize:
I have

- A good, brand new computer with a BD drive upstairs connected to the home network
- An HDCP-compatible HDTV downstairs
- A Wii connected to the network, and the ability to connect something else to the network
- A spare computer which can run Windows and Linux, which I can put downstairs, but which does not have a BD drive.

I want

- To watch Blu-Ray discs on the HDTV
- To spend as little money as possible

I do NOT care about

- Lag, as long as it's consistent (If I see the video and hear the audio 5 seconds after the computer plays it, that's OK as long as the playback is smooth and the audio is in sync with the video)
- Reinstalling the spare computer's OS
- Hacking my Wii or either computer, as long as it takes < a day.

Is this currently possible, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had no problem displaying 1080p resolution from my computer over a 50 ft. flat HDMI cable made my GTMax.  They're relatively cheap at around $30 for a 50 ft. cable, such as http://amzn.com/B00356Z5T2.

Read this for more info about the relationship between cable length, signal quality, and bit rates: http://www.bluejeanscable.com/articles/how-long-can-hdmi-run.htm

Without connecting it directly with a cable, you'll run into issues caused by the DEVIL (a.k.a. DRM, HDCP, etc.), and hardware devices that comply with the DEVIL to restrict the flow of information.

I just hope some hardware manufacturer in China puts that [leaked HDCP key](http://pastebin.com/kqD56TmU) to good use soon, so I can [do whatever I want with an HD signal](http://www.engadget.com/2010/09/14/hdcp-master-key-supposedly-released-unlocks-hdtv-copy-protect/), whether I want to stream it over my network to my TV or whatever.

Comment: the "leaked HDCP key" is only a partial, and Intel has already stated that even a fully decrypted key would need to be implemented on the silicon... a feat that will be difficult even for the Chinese.  http://www.foxnews.com/scitech/2010/09/16/intel-confirms-hdtv-code-cracked/

Comment: @typoknig I don't know much about the copy protection, except that nothing anybody tries to do can stop people pirating content, but it can easily stop the everyday user (such as myself) from using it easily.  However, I see no reason why it would need to be implemented in hardware or why doing so would be difficult - there are such things as modchips, after all, and somebody could "easily" (read "I don't personally know how, but in my ignorance I assume any hardware guy could do it in his sleep") directly control every bit on the wires from an OS, making it software-implementable.

Comment: thanks; I'll see if I can find a long enough cable (the 75' in the question was an actual rough measurement I did, so anything less probably isn't long enough and I'd prefer something longer)

Comment: @typoknig  No, it's not a "partial" key.  It's the full HDCP master key.  Did you get confused by the caption on that link you posted, where it describes the image at the top as a picture of a "tiny portion" of the master key?  The entire key is in fact available http://pastebin.com/kqD56TmU and obviously it would be implemented in the silicon (because of high computation requirements)... probably as a very simple chip that goes between your HDMI cable and TV to remove the HDCP from the signal before it reaches your display or capture device.

Comment: I stand corrected.  On the news (and at the link I posted) they made it seem like only part of the master key had been found.

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept this back when it was fresh; I'm just now revisiting the issue and am going to make an old laptop into an HTCP if I can get the hard drive quiet enough, etc. I expect the solution would have worked, though.